# How can I fix this array table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

I have written a fairly simple array table using 3 values that are defined by the user. These 3 values determine the value of a variable. I have written similar code before but for some reason I can not figure out why this one is not working. The table is large so I am sorry for the size...

```
var ssRidgeQty=document.getElementById("ssRidgeTrim").value;

var ssRidgeWidth=document.getElementById("ssRidgeWidth").value;

var ssRidgeColorUp;
if (ssColorChoice=="galvalume")
{
    ssRidgeColorUp="1";
}
else if (ssColorChoice=="Dark Gray" || ssColorChoice=="Antique Bronze" ||     ssColorChoice=="Rural Red" || ssColorChoice=="Dark Green" || ssColorChoice=="Fern Green")
{
    ssRidgeColorUp="2";
}
else if (ssColorChoice=="metallic copper")
{
    ssRidgeColorUp="3";
}
else if (ssColorChoice=="none" && ssRidgeQty>0)
{
    ssRidgeColorUp=0;
    alert ("please choose a ss color");
}
else
{
    ssRidgeColorUp="4";
}

var ssRidgeCap = new Array();
//retail, galvalume
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[14]] = 21.75;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[16]] = 28.1;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[18]] = 31.3;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[20]] = 34.5;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[22]] = 37.7;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[24]] = 40.9;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[26]] = 44.1;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[28]] = 47.3;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[30]] = 50.5;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[32]] = 53.7;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[34]] = 56.9;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[36]] = 60.1;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[38]] = 63.3;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[40]] = 66.5;
//retail, Kynar
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[14]] = 25.85;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[16]] = 31.3;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[18]] = 34.9;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[20]] = 38.5;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[22]] = 42.1;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[24]] = 45.7;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[26]] = 49.3;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[28]] = 52.9;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[30]] = 56.5;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[32]] = 60.1;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[34]] = 63.7;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[36]] = 67.3;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[38]] = 70.9;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[2],[40]] = 74.5;
//retail, Metallic Copper
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[14]] = 26.55;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[16]] = 35.3;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[18]] = 39.4;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[20]] = 43.5;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[22]] = 47.6;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[24]] = 51.7;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[26]] = 55.8;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[28]] = 59.9;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[30]] = 64;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[32]] = 68.1;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[34]] = 72.2;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[36]] = 76.3;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[38]] = 80.4;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[3],[40]] = 84.5;
//retail, Syl-Poly
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[14]] = 22.5;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[16]] = 28.9;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[18]] = 32.2;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[20]] = 35.5;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[22]] = 38.8;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[24]] = 42.1;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[26]] = 45.4;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[28]] = 48.7;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[30]] = 52;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[32]] = 55.3;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[34]] = 58.6;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[36]] = 61.9;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[38]] = 65.2;
ssRidgeCap [[0],[4],[40]] = 68.5;
//Contractor, galvalume
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[14]] = 20.38;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[16]] = 26.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[18]] = 29.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[20]] = 32.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[22]] = 35.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[24]] = 38.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[26]] = 41.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[28]] = 44.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[30]] = 47.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[32]] = 50.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[34]] = 53.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[36]] = 56.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[38]] = 59.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[1],[40]] = 62.5;
//Contractor, Kynar
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[14]] = 25.2;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[16]] = 30.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[18]] = 34;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[20]] = 37.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[22]] = 41;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[24]] = 44.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[26]] = 48;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[28]] = 51.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[30]] = 55;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[32]] = 58.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[34]] = 62;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[36]] = 65.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[38]] = 69;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[2],[40]] = 72.5;
//Contractor, Meta1llic Copper
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[14]] = 25.85;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[16]] = 34.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[18]] = 38.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[20]] = 42.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[22]] = 46.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[24]] = 50.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[26]] = 54.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[28]] = 58.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[30]] = 62.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[32]] = 66.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[34]] = 70.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[36]] = 74.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[38]] = 78.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[3],[40]] = 82.5;
//Contractor, Syl-Poly
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[14]] = 21.75;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[16]] = 28.1;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[18]] = 31.3;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[20]] = 34.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[22]] = 37.7;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[24]] = 40.9;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[26]] = 44.1;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[28]] = 47.3;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[30]] = 50.5;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[32]] = 53.7;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[34]] = 56.9;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[36]] = 60.1;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[38]] = 63.3;
ssRidgeCap [[1],[4],[40]] = 66.5;
//Wholesale, galvalume
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[14]] = 19;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[16]] = 24.9;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[18]] = 27.7;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[20]] = 30.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[22]] = 33.3;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[24]] = 36.1;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[26]] = 38.9;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[28]] = 41.7;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[30]] = 44.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[32]] = 47.3;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[34]] = 50.1;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[36]] = 52.9;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[38]] = 55.7;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[1],[40]] = 58.5;
//Wholesale, Kynar
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[14]] = 22.48;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[16]] = 26.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[18]] = 29.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[20]] = 32.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[22]] = 35.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[24]] = 38.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[26]] = 41.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[28]] = 44.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[30]] = 47.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[32]] = 50.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[34]] = 53.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[36]] = 56.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[38]] = 59.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[2],[40]] = 62.5;
//Wholesale, Meta1llic Copper
    ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[14]] = 23.15;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[16]] = 30.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[18]] = 34;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[20]] = 37.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[22]] = 41;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[24]] = 44.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[26]] = 48;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[28]] = 51.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[30]] = 55;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[32]] = 58.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[34]] = 62;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[36]] = 65.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[38]] = 69;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[3],[40]] = 72.5;
//Wholesale, Syl-Poly
    ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[14]] = 19.1;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[16]] = 26.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[18]] = 29.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[20]] = 32.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[22]] = 35.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[24]] = 38.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[26]] = 41.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[28]] = 44.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[30]] = 47.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[32]] = 50.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[34]] = 53.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[36]] = 56.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[38]] = 59.5;
ssRidgeCap [[2],[4],[40]] = 62.5;    

var ssRidgePrice = ssRidgeCap [[priceLevel],[ssRidgeColorUp],[ssRidgeWidth]];


document.getElementById("ssRidgeTest4").innerHTML=ssRidgePrice;
```

The result is always coming from the last set of arrays labeled Wholesale syl-pol. If I change the width then the value changes but if I change the price level or the color (the first 2 [] in the array, nothing changes. For some reason these values are stuck on [2] and [4].

If you need any other reference just ask and I will post it. I need urgent help

(ps. Price Level is set by a radio button labled 1, 2, 3, When I do a test to print out the three deciding variables "priceLevel", "ssRidgeColorUp", and ssRidgeWidth, they always come up correctly but the array is not picking them up?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't use an object array that describes these things?  Also, can you post a jsfiddle?  I would be interested in seeing an example of it.

Comment: What is a jsFiddle? Using a large array just seamed easier. I just cant for the life of me figure out why this is not working. even if I tell the code to write ssRidgeCap is starts printing the values at 19.1

Comment: JSFiddle.net is a neat little site where you can check code or share it with others on the fly.  It will go a long way in finding out the context in which your using the code and it could be something other than what you have posted causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to use a multi-dimensional array

```
var ssRidgeCap = new Array();

ssRidgeCap[0] = [];
ssRidgeCap[0][1] = [];
ssRidgeCap[0][1][14]= 21.75;
```

Then it can be access using

```
ssRidgeCap[0][1][14]
```

Comment: I think this may work however do I have to create another array at ssRidgeCap[0][2]

Comment: @ABBryan yes, that is the whole point of multi dimensional array

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an array use an object

```
var ssRidgeCap = {
    pl_0 : {
        rc_1 : {
            rw_14 : 21.75,
            rw_16 : 28.1
        },
        rc_2 : {
            rw_14 : 25.85,
            rw_16 : 31.3
        }
    },
    pl_1 : {
        rc_1 : {
            rw_14 : 20.38,
            rw_16 : 26.5
        },
        rc_2 : {
            rw_14 : 25.2,
            rw_16 : 30.5
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
var ssRidgePrice = ssRidgeCap['pl_' + priceLevel]['rc_' + ssRidgeColorUp]['rw_' + ssRidgeWidth];
```

Comment: For updating these prices an object would be much more time consuming. This array should work and I would rather find out what is wrong with it.

Comment: @ABBryan AFAK the array as modelled by you will not work, if you need you have make it into a three dimensional array

Comment: @ABBryan model it along the lines of `var ssRidgeCap = new Array();

ssRidgeCap[0] = [];
ssRidgeCap[0][1] = [];
ssRidgeCap[0][1][14]]= 21.75;`

Answer (score 0):

Why not define a multidimensional array in one command ?

The syntax for accessing one multidim array element (say 2 dim) is

```
a[i][j] = X;
```

Also when you access an not existing element of a defined array, all the preceding elements are created, if not existing.

When you access an (non) existing element of a non existing array an error will occur.

```
var a = [];
a[5] = 4; // ok, elements 0,1,2,3,4 are created and set to undefined
a[6][4] = 53; // not ok, error, cannot convert undefined to object.
```

An example definition

```
var ssRidgeCap = 
[
   // 0
  [
     // 0, 0
     [ 54, 35, 64 ],
     // 0, 1
     [ 54, 23, 66 ]
   ],
   // 1
      // 1, 0
      [ 23, 6, 75],
      // 1, 1
      [ 22,  66, 22]
   ]
];
```

Comment: so this...ssRidgeCap [[0],[1],[14]] = 21.75; should be this...ssRidgeCap [0,1,14] = 21.75 ?

Comment: Maybe you need to be a little more carefull. It should be ssRidgeCap [0][1][14] = 21.75